# circleci error cut: the delimiter must be a single character

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci, cicd

I'm looking to fetch the new version number which is created from semantic-release package for circleci.

```
  - run: |
      VERSION_ENV=$(cat bash.env)
      echo $VERSION_ENV
      NEXT_VERSION=$(echo $VERSION_ENV | cut -d /›/ -f2)
```

The `.circleci/config.yml` file above has a step where it takes the value from `bash.env` and tries to tidy the value using `cut`.

`bash.env` should have a value that looks like `[8:04:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  The next release version is 5.2.0-task.21`

When running the `config.yml` it fails on this step and responds with the following.

```
[8:04:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ The next release version is 5.2.0-task.21
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
Try 'cut --help' for more information.

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

Any advice on resolving this would be much appreciated.

In a previous `job` the following is run,

```
      command: |
         npx semantic-release --dry-run | grep -i 'The next release version is' | sed -E 's/.* ([[:digit:].]+)$/\1/'  > bash.env
         cat bash.env
```

Just wanted to show what was being sent to `bash.env`.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `read` to read the `bash.env` contents into a variable and then bash parameter expansion to parse the version:

```
read -r a <bash.env ; echo "${a##*›}"
 ℹ  The next release version is 5.2.0-task.21
```

- or -

```
read -r a <bash.env ; echo "${a##* }"
5.2.0-task.21
```